# How to infer a sameAs relation between objects with the same name

Tags: relationship, rdf, sparql, owl, reasoning

I want to infer a owl:sameAs relation between objects that have the same value for a property using RDF reasoning.

i.e.

- object1 dc:title someTitle
- object2 dc:title someTitle

What would be the code to infer the relation between all objects with matching titles?

Also, can I do that when the properties are not the same?

i.e.

- object1 dc:title someTitle
- object2 rdf:title someTitle

Regards

Comment: "What would be the code to infer the relation between all objects with matching titles?"  This is not a specific enough question.  RDF doesn't provide very much in the way of semantics.  RDFS provides some, but not enough to do what you're talking about.  OWL provides enough, and you can do an inverse functional property axiom to get the results that you want.  You could also construct the triples you want by using an SPARQL construct query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not in RDF or RDFS

RDF doesn't have a whole lot of semantics built in, and while RDFS provides some, I don't think that either is enough to get you the kind of reasoning that you're looking for.  However, since you're looking to create owl:sameAs links, you might be using an OWL reasoner, in which case this isn't too hard, and it's very easy in SPARQL too.  The rest of the answer covers these two cases.

### In OWL

You just need to declare that the property at hand is an [inverse functional (object) property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Inverse-Functional_Object_Properties):

> ### [9.2.8 Inverse-Functional Object Properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Inverse-Functional_Object_Properties)
>
> An object property inverse functionality axiom
>   InverseFunctionalObjectProperty( OPE ) states that the object property
>   expression OPE is inverse-functional — that is, for each individual x,
>   there can be at most one individual y such that y is connected by OPE
>   with x.

A classic example of this is for any type of unique identifier, such as a taxpayer ID number.  E.g.,

```
ex:hasSSN a owl:InverseFunctionalProperty .
:JohnDoe :hasSSN :ssnXXX-XX-XXXX .
:JDoe :hasSSN :ssnXXX-XX-XXXX .
```

From these, we can infer with OWL reasoning that

```
:JohnDoe owl:sameAs :JDoe .
```

Note that only object properties can be inverse functional (though I think that some reasoners will handle inverse functional datatype properties);  this means that you may have to "wrap" some values as I did above, creating an IRI individual :ssnXXX-XX-XXX rather than using the string "XXX-XX-XXXX".  See 
[What's the problem with inverse-functional datatype properties?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/12490/whats-the-problem-with-inverse-functional-datatype-properties) for some discussion about why.

Now, if you have two different properties, then you could make them both subproperties of some new property, and make the new property inverse functional. For instance

```
:hasSSN rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasTaxpayerIDOrSSN .
:hasTaxpayerID rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasTaxpayerIDOrSSN .
:hasTaxpayerIDOrSSN a owl:InverseFunctionalProperty .
```

Then from

```
:JohnDoe :hasSSN :ssnXXX-XX-XXXX .
:JDoe :hasSSN :ssnXXX-XX-XXXX .
```

you could infer

```
:JohnDoe :hasTaxpayerIDOrSSN :ssnXXX-XX-XXXX .
:JDoe    :hasTaxpayerIDOrSSN :ssnXXX-XX-XXXX .
```

and from that, that

```
:JohnDoe owl:sameAs :JDoe .
```

### In SPARQL

In SPARQL this is pretty easy, too.  First, some data to query:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .

:JohnDoe :hasSSN :ssnXXX-XX-XXX .
:JDoe :hasSSN :ssnXXX-XX-XXX .
```

Then we can define a simple **construct** query:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

construct { ?x owl:sameAs ?y }
where { ?z ^:hasSSN ?x, ?y }
```

```
@prefix :      <urn:ex:> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

:JDoe   owl:sameAs  :JohnDoe , :JDoe .

:JohnDoe  owl:sameAs  :JohnDoe , :JDoe .
```

If you want to use multiple properties, you can just use an alternation in the property path.  Here's data, a query, and the results:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .

:JohnDoe :hasSSN :ssnXXX-XX-XXX .
:JDoe :hasTaxpayerID :ssnXXX-XX-XXX .
```

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

construct { ?x owl:sameAs ?y }
where { ?z ^(:hasSSN|:hasTaxpayerID) ?x, ?y }
```

```
@prefix :      <urn:ex:> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

:JDoe   owl:sameAs  :JDoe , :JohnDoe .

:JohnDoe  owl:sameAs  :JDoe , :JohnDoe .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the SILK framework: http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/bizer/silk/

I have used it successfully several times to find owl:sameAs relationships between entities from different datasets (e.g., if you have a dataset with provinces and you want to find which entities from DBpedia have the same province name). As far as I know you can use it to match elements from the same dataset as well.

The advantage of using SILK is that you have several algorithms to compare entities with similar value (e.g., someTitle, some Title, Sometitle and SOMETITLE would be matched). You can play with the filters to get the results you want. The only disadvantage is that if you lower the distance value to compare SILK could match values like "some Title" and "som Title", which could be wrong depending on your use case.